# Application was slow and even stuck and had to restart the database server

Tags: database, performance, restart

What would be the good steps to troubleshoot a situation where the application was and even stuck and I had to restart the database server?

The application was written in Java and ran different reports/queries few time then the application became so slow and stuck eventually. Then, had to restart the SQL database server again to get it back to work. It was obviously running out the resource on the server.

Comment: trace the database slow query  by logging

Comment: Did the application release resources appropriately?  Does JDBC release the resource when you close the connection?  Did you close the connection?  It could easily be the server that is not handling things as well as you'd like, but it could also be that the application was gummed up by too many not yet completely dead DB-related resources.

Comment: @Yu Jiaao It was old method that the sql queries were coding within Java not store procedures at the db. Still be able to do logging?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Good point. I need to double check that. Thanks.

Comment: You can profile database by db server tools, for example SQL Server Profile for MS SQL Server or `show processlist` for MySQL to check what the db server is exactly doing when you app halt.